# Logic minimization guarantees of arbitrary subcircuits?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to better understand logic circuit minimization. Say you try and minimize the number of gates in some simple logic circuit. After minimization is completed, I choose an arbitrary sub-circuit (some group of connected gates). Is that sub-circuit always guaranteed to be as small as possible, or at least as small as possible given whatever particular algorithm is being used?

Comment: Think logically. If you have a sub-block which is calculating a certain function, and you can replace it with a smaller sub-block calculating the same function - then the whole circuit can be minimized with this smaller sub-block. Meaning that it wasn't minimal before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule yes, if it's truly minimized, sub-blocks will also be minimized.

However, minimizing logic is sometimes not the same thing as minimizing devices or gates.

In some cases you can see odd logic configurations which are done solely to reduce the parts count by making use of unused gates in existing devices. By using spare gates rather than adding new device(s) you can sometimes reduce the parts count and cost.

For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsHOE7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice the second circuit would use three different logic device types, whereas the first uses a single chip. Logically they are the same.